# SSIS - DataFlow - Set a value for each row from a procedure stocked result

Tags: ssis, dataflow

For a SSIS, i have to transfer data from a server to another but on the final destination, i have a column like ID.
For determinate the new ID of each row, i have to execute a stored procedure on the final server.

Is-it possible to do that in DataFlow and avoid the Foreach Loop in ControlFlow ?

Regards,
Guillaume.

Comment: Did you tried the "OLE DB command task" in the data flow? If you use Stored procedure will be called for each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this task using `OLEDB command` . If your SP has a `return` statement than try to capture the return value and map it with your input column

```
exec ? = dbo.ReturnID
```

This statement will create a `@RETURN_VALUE` which you need to map with the input `ID` column .Remember to create an Input `ID column` in the source itself as NULL or any value so that you can map this column in `OLEDB component` with the  `@RETURN_VALUE`

```
Update 1 :
```

Try this :-

```
EXEC dbo.my_sp 'p1', 'p2',@variable_name=? output
```

`@variable_name` is the output variable name used in your stored procedure

Comment: Ok I had add an empty column in my OleDb source and linked to an OleDb Command. But i don't understrand how to store the result of SP in the empty column. The Column Mappings tab is empty.

Comment: When you write this statment `exec ? = dbo.ReturnID` in `oledb command` it will automatically create `@return_value` in `Available Destination column` in `Columns mapping tab`

Comment: OK but the SP has a last parameter in OUTPUT, so in the SqlCommand i set : DECLARE @ TEST INT; EXEC dbo.my_sp 'p1', 'p2', @ TEST And nothing appears in the tab. I tried your syntax but i got errors.

Comment: Ok my mistake. I  finally understand your answer. It's great ! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think it is. I suggest following the DataFlow task with an Execute SQL task that will execute your stored procedure.

Comment: As per OP ,the SP is going to create a new ID for each row .If you get this value in `Execute SQL Task` then how will you map in `Data Flow Task` .Chunks of rows are processed in `DFT`

Comment: Yes, the problem is for each row :s